# Автоматическое открытие входящей ссылки

Tags: алгоритм, ссылки, соцсети, вкладки

Как сделать чтобы при появлении ссылки она автоматически открывалась?Например в соц.сети в сообщении мне прислали ссылку и она автоматом открылась?

Comment: В благих целях использовать хотите?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду свою машину и свой браузер? Поставьте GreaseMonkey и напишите для этого userscript.

Answer (score 1):

В консоли использовать вот это можно:

```
 var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.src =
 "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

 setInterval(function() {   $('твой селектор до тех ссылок которые появляются').click().remove(); }, 2000);
```